# Getting ConnectException: failed to connect to 192.168.2.100 (port 22) ECONNREFUSED with Android and JSCH

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I'm getting a java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 192.168.2.100 (port 22): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) when connecting to a server via SSH with [JSCH-0.1.54](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) on Android.

The firewall is configured to let the IP adress through.
SSH connection from Windows to the server is possible via Putty.
The server's IP adress is alright.

What else can it be?

The code I'm using is below:

```
protected Long doInBackground(String... params)
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("root", "192.168.2.100", 22);
        session.setPassword("Password");
        session.setTimeout(10000);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(props);
        session.connect();
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        if(params[0]=="poweroff")
        {
            LogPublic("Server wird heruntergefahren");
        }
        else if(params[0]=="reboot")
        {
            LogPublic("Server wird neugestartet");
        }
        channel.setCommand(params[0]);
        channel.connect();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        jsch.removeAllIdentity();
        jsch = null;
        return new Long(1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogPublic(ex.getMessage());
        return new Long(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the exception stack? Also what is the IP and Mask of your android host? Are you running the app on a real device connected to the network or using an emulator?

Comment: Can you connect to the host using a standalone SSH terminal app from the device?

Comment: @Ahmed Ghonim: I can do this. Will add it later today. I now suppose that the problem is with my DHCP... My mobile has the same IP address as my NAS :/ I'm running the app on a real device connected to the network.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: No, I can't, I already tried with [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=en)

Comment: Well, then you do not have a programming question.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem... My NAS' IP address was inside my DHCP range... Now set it outside of this and it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the server's static IP address out of my router's DHCP range as this caused an IP conflict.